# Cannot find/update firmware for IBM x3650 M2

Tags: ibm, bios, ipmi, firmware, ibm-xseries

I am trying to revive an old IBM x3650 M2 server, but am running into trouble with IMM/IPMI related to the FW being almost as old as the server itself. Server is from 2010, firmware is from '09 (UEFI) and '11 (IMM/DSA) and is running ESXi.

I checked [the official supportsite (that has no firmware at all for the server)](https://datacentersupport.lenovo.com/dk/da/products/servers/system-x/system-x3650-m2/7947/7947k7g/downloads/driver-list/) and did my best Google-fu, but have not found any useable FW download. The problem I'm having (IMM changes "Failed in the backend") is "common" and others have resolved this same issue with a firmware update, so that's my focus.

There might be other ways to find/update FW that I haven't thought of, and any ideas are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On IBM site there are a lot more fresh firmware/updates. You can visit this [site](https://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/systemx/selectFixes?parent=System%20x3650%20M2&product=ibm/systemx/7947&&platform=All&function=all#UEFI) and select what you want to update.

IMM is from 2016

UEFI is from 2018

Comment: Thank you for the excellent suggestion.
It looks like it has what I'm looking for (weird that it was so hard for me to find).

But after posting I started to poke at XClarity, specifically the "Lenovo XClarity Essentials Bootable Media Creator" which also does the trick (and I'm kicking myself for not taking that extra step before posting).